# How do i authenticate multiple models like users,agents,admin and so on

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I am building an API which has many resource users, for example 
I have these table in my database `users`,`agents`,`drivers`and `admin`

if they want to access the resource or to check their details they should login to see so how do I do that

Should I go for `laravel passport` and do this in all the models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;  //for agents, drivers, admin
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable  
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable; //for agents, drivers, admin
}
```

I am so confused now, please point me in right direction.

Thank You!

Comment: what exactly you are trying to get through api??

Comment: @SoniyaReddy the api has all the users details and drivers agents details, if a user login he can see his profile and the drive who is carrying their things(just his details) and under which agent the driver is, and if the agent logs in he can add the drivers there are multiple agents based on place how can add any number of drivers under them and so on stuff,

Comment: whether he is a  driver or agent or user or admin login must be only one right?? based on their credentials you need to show the details right??

Comment: @Soniya Reddy no all the models are there in the database, all are required, it's driver and agent and user and admin

Answer (score 1):

No Problem!

Just use Roles !!!

You will have one user model that will deal with all the AUTH... 
and for each user you will assign a role 'agents'

and then for example:

```
if (Auth::user()->hasRole('agent')){
   ....
}else if( Auth::user()->hasRole('driver')){
   ....
}else if( Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
   ...
}else if( Auth::user()->hasRole('support')){
   ...
}
```

Got it?
you can also had permission for any role like:

```
public function hasPermission(Permission $permission)
{
    return $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
}
```

just search for "LaravelUser ACL Roles and Permissions"

Comment: @ Dani Banai thanks for your time, i'm a kinda newbie in laravel, should i deffine all the roles in my `User` model,

Comment: No
you need to create role model! Just watch this as a start(part1 to part4): https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/13

Comment: thank you so much for you time i really appreciate it, i'm building an `API` for `mobile and web app`, the `agents` will be having mobile app where he can login to `CRUD` the `drivers` where as the `admin` will be given with `web app` where he can `CRUD` the `agents` since this is an `API` there is no `session` to store the auth of `agents and admin` so i should provide `access_token` for both agents(app) and admin(web) right? this is where i am stuck, i should make the Agent and 'Admin' model authenticatable to achive this? or my implementation is not good? thank you